# Inserting spacing between the plus sign and a number

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to write an equation involving math `$$ ...< X_u,X_v>+ 0$$`, but the plus sign and zero end up too close to each other when printed.

How can I insert a decent amount of spacing in between the two symbols?

It's odd that there is spacing between `< X_u,X_v >` and the plus sign, but no spacing between the plus sign and the zero.

Comment: Maybe you seek `...\langle X_u,X_v\rangle+ 0`?  Or, if you still prefer the look of `<` and `>`, then `...\mathopen{<} X_u,X_v\mathclose{>}+ 0`.

Comment: because you have used `>` (the relation not a closing delimiter) the `+` is interpreted as a prefix operator for +0  not an infix operator which would have space either side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angle brackets as opening and closing atoms are given by `\langle` and `\rangle`.  If one still wants the look of `<` and `>`, then one must designate them as opening and closing atoms to get the right spacing (otherwise, they are treated as math relational symbols `\mathrel`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
...\langle X_u,X_v\rangle+ 0
\]
\[
...\mathopen{<} X_u,X_v\mathclose{>}+ 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]